# React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my code

```
function App() {
    const [isImportant, setIsImportant] = useState("Yes")
    
    
    function handleClick() {
        setIsImportant("No")
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="state">
            <h1 className="state--title">Is state important to know?</h1>
            <div className="state--value" onClick ={setIsImportant("No")} >
              {isImportant}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image]

However I get the error which says 'Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.'

If someone can explain why the error is happening it would be grateful!!

Answer (score 5):

## Problem

Looking at your current code, this part:

```
onClick ={setIsImportant("No")}
```

is calling **setIsImportant** every time your page renders, and because this function modifies state of your component, it tries to re-render the same component again, causing an infinite loop.

## Solution

There are two ways of solving this issue, either by wrapping **setIsImportant** method in a wrapper:

```
 <div className="state--value" onClick ={() => setIsImportant("No")} >
                  {isImportant}
    </div>
```

or by simply using the function you just created:

```
<div className="state--value" onClick ={handleClick} >
              {isImportant}
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what you've changed and how it fixes the issue.

Comment: He did explain the problem and how to fix it..

Comment: Yes I did, but after editing my answer. Idruskis was right.

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` handler needs a function -- but what you pass is the *result* of calling `setIsImportant("No")`, thus `setIsImportant("No")` is called immediately when rendering.

To fix, pass a function instead. You actually already have one -- `handleClick` -- so use `onClick={handleClick}`.

Answer (score 0):

- You are invoking the `setIsImportant` in `onClick` directly
- Everytime render happens `setIsImportant("No")` will be fired and
  setState causes the component to re-render and then re-rendering  will
  fire `setIsImportant("No")` again and so on.. which leads to infinite
  re-render.
- You are setting the state again and again and it never stops.

**Solution**

To prevent this you need to pass a function to `onClick` handler

```
onClick ={() => setIsImportant("No")}
```